# Best asp.net calendar/schedule component?

Tags: asp.net, calendar

I'm looking for the BEST asp.net calendar/schedule component that it out there.
I like the look of google calendar, and it absolutely needs to be a native .net component, which can be customized.

I don't mind if it is part of a bigger framework (like telerik, for example).
Links to samples would be great.

Comment: Best is very subjective could you please post some evaluation criteria?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/)'s ASP.NET Controls are really good.

They provide ASP.NET AJAX and ASP.NET MVC controls.

Calendar:
http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/calendar/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx

Scheduler:
http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/scheduler/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx

Comment: Telerik is buggy and overpriced.

Answer (score 6):

If you are really looking for the best one you need to see mine ;-)

DayPilot Lite (open-source):

http://www.daypilot.org/demo/Lite/

DayPilot Pro (commercial):

http://www.daypilot.org/demo/Calendar/GoogleLike.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you're trying to do [BaseCalendar](http://basecalendar.codeplex.com/) may work for you. It doesn't come with scheduler, but it is highly customizable. A few demos are included in the project.

Answer (score 0):

Check out ComponentOne's WebSchedule and WebCalendar 
Live demo: http://helpcentral.componentone.com/c1webexamples/

Answer (score 0):

DevExpress currently have 60 controls for free:

http://www.microsoft.com/web/content.aspx?id=15-helpful-in-browser-web-development-tools

I'm not sure if the Calendar is included with these, but they do have one and you can try it out.

Anthony,
[www.codersbarn.com](http://www.codersbarn.com) :-)

Answer (score 0):

try [web2cal](http://web2cal.com). That is pretty good. Slick looking and easy to customize

Answer (score 0):

The ComponentOne Schedule and Calendar are really easy to use. They can be dropped on the form and connected to eachother with a single property. Also, the scheduler comes with a built-in xml data store so no code is required to get it working!

Check out this [scheduler and calendar sample](http://demo.componentone.com/aspnet/controlexplorer/C1Schedule/CalendarNavigation.aspx)